# Cannot reset root password through Linux command menu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, password, grub, xubuntu

When I run through the full sequence of commands given to me to reset my root password, the Linux Command menu says I correctly reset my password, however I cannot use the password i set it to. The following is my full path to reset my password.

enter the the GRUB menu, press <kbd>enter</kbd> on advanced options for Ubuntu, then press  <kbd>e</kbd> on Ubuntu, with Linux 4.15.0-70-generic to edit it.

I edit the line that starts with `linux` and delete `ro quiet splash $vt_handoff` and replace it with `rw init=/bin/bash` and hit <kbd>f10</kbd>. I have also kept `ro` without changing it to `rw`, and it does not change the outcome.

after this i enter the following commands into the prompt given.

```
root@(none):/# mount -o remount,rw / && mount -o remount,rw /proc
```

NOTE: when I start typing the above command, it prints

```
[    21.375791]random: crng init done
[    21.378159]random: 7 urandom warning(s) missed due to ratelimiting
```

when I enter the mount command, I get

```
[    74.858546] EXT4-fs (sdal): re-mounted. Opts: errors=remount-ro

root@(none):/# passwd
Enter new UNIX password: I entered a 6 digit long password
Retype new UNIX password: 
passwd: password updated successfully

root@(none)/# sync

root@(none)/# exec /sbin/init
```

to exit and boot to linux

After I do these, the root password still does not set to what I try to change it to. I check by trying to reset the password in the Linux terminal through passwd and by trying to log in remotely using puTTY on my home computer. neither accept the "changed" password. I am running Xubuntu on a 2007 Dell Inspiron 1520. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: that is not a GRUB menu ... that is a linux command prompt

Comment: Are you logging in with `root` or with a regular user?